# how to use urlhelper to include rails 3 custom data- attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3 and found that if I add 
    :remote => :true, there will be added to the  tag the data-remote = true attribute. But I can't find a way to add custom data- attributes to the urlhelper. The followings won't work:

```
<%= link_to projects_path, :history => "new"%>
<%= link_to projects_path, :data-history => "new"%> #this throws an error
<%= link_to projects_path, :data_history => "new"%>
```

What I want to generate is:
    New Project

anyone?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What about:

```
<%= link_to 'New Project', new_project_path, 'data-history' => 'new' %>
```

( http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to )

Comment: Hey Sled, thanks for replying. I tried that, it gives me     <a href="/projects/new" data-remote="true" history="new">New Project</a>  see that the history="new", it's there but not with data- previx. do you know if there's a way to add data-prefix to it?

Comment: I've edited my answer, it should work now :) the error was, that you can't use "-" in symbols, you have to write it as literal.

Comment: thanks for this, didn't realise you could put arbitrary keys into the options hash!

Comment: You can use just about any character in a symbol as long as your wrap it in quotes. For example: `{ :'data-history' => 'new' }` would work fine.

Answer (score 10):

This is an elegant solution:

```
<%= link_to "foo", foo_path, data: { foo: "bar" } %>
```